# dynamic sequelize condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

1. I have a json array which includes conditions like this

   ```
   conditionArr = [{
       "column": "customer_date",
       "operator": "eq",
       "type": "day",
       "value": "-9"
       "connect": "or"

   },{
       "column": "register_date",
       "operator": "eq",
       "type": "day",
       "value": "-9",
       "connect": "and"
   },{
       "column": "reading_date",
       "operator": "eq",
       "type": "day",
       "value": "-9",
       "connect": "or"
   },{
       "column": "submit_date",
       "operator": "eq",
       "type": "day",
       "value": "-9",

   }
   ];
   ```
2. I haven't seen any docs about how to create dynamic where op conditions on sequelize. I would like to build query Array object with these conditions and put it on where clause like this

   ```
   var query = Helper.buildQuery(conditions,template.type_name);
   UserData.findAll({
             where: query,
             raw: true
   });
   ```

   function buildQuery(conditions,templateType) {
       var query = Array();
       var i = 0;

   ```
   conditions.forEach(function () {
       var column = conditions[i].column;
       var value = conditions[i].value;
       var type = conditions[i].type;
       var operator = conditions[i].operator;
       var connector = conditions[i].connect;
       var queryObject = new Object();


       if(column.startsWith('Data')){
           var regex = RegExp('>(.*?)[-|\(]','gm');
           var match;
           var matches = [];

           while ((match = regex.exec(column)) != null) {
               matches.push(match[1]);
           }

           var temp_column = '';
           var ii = 0;
           matches.forEach( function() {
               temp_column += matches[ii] + '.';
               ii++;
           });
           temp_column = temp_column.substring(0, temp_column.length - 1); 
           column = temp_column;
       }

       if (value == 'null') {
           queryObject = { [column]: null };
       }
       else if (type == 'day' || type == 'week' || type == 'month' || type == 'year') {
           var target = moment(new Date()).add(value, type);

           switch (type) {
               case 'day':
                   target.hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
                   break;
               case 'week':
                   target.day(0).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
               case 'month':
                   target.week(0).day(0).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
               case 'year':
                target.month(0).week(0).day(0).hour(0).minute(0).second(0).millisecond(0);
                   break;
               default:
                   break;
           }

           var target_end = moment(target).add(1, type);
           queryObject = { [column]: { [Op.gt]: target.toDate(), [Op.lt]: 
           target_end.toDate() } };
       } else if (type == 'string' || conditions[i].type == 'integer' || 
           conditions[i].type == 'date') {
           if(type === 'string' && operator ==='eq'){
               operator = 'like';
               queryObject = { [column]: { [operator]: value } };
           }
           else if(type ==='integer' && operator ==='eq'){
               queryObject = { [column]: value };
           }
           else{
               queryObject = { [column]: { [operator]: value } };
           }

       }


       query.push(queryObject);
       i++;

   return query;
   ```